# React native not waiting for response from API before continuing

Tags: reactjs, native

I have just started playing about with react native and I have a problem that functions aren't waiting for responses before continuing.

So in Chrome my console log displays:

> userStore
>
> this state contents
>
> returned data from api / userstore [object Object]

Basically getUserDetails is executed and in that time while the api is being called the setData function runs, and it completes before the api result has been returned.

I would like the getUserDetails functio to complete before setData is called.

I have had a look at resources online, but am at a loss. The code I am using is below (This has been stripped down for ease of reading nb. I am using mobx)

UserScreen.js

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: null
    };
}

async componentDidMount() {
  this.props.commonStore.setLoading(true);
  await this.props.userStore.getUserDetails('1');        
  this.setData();
  this.props.commonStore.setLoading(false);   
}

setData() {
    this.setState({
      userDetails: this.props.userStore.userDetails
  });
  console.log('userStore' + this.props.userStore.userDetails)
  console.log('this state contents '+ this.state.userDetails);
}

render () {
  if(this.props.commonStore.isLoading===false) {
    return (<View><Text>Ready!!</Text></View>)
  }else{}
    return (<View><Text>Loading</Text></View>)
  }
}
```

UserStore.js

```
@action getUserDetails = (userID) => {
    axios.get('http://192.168.1.9/user/' + userID)
    .then(response => {
      console.log('returned data from api / userstore ' +response.data.user);
      this.userdetails = response.data.user;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.error = error
    })   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have stumbled upon the beauty of Mobx, you need to move towards a stateless solution i.e.:

UserScreen.js

```
componentDidMount() {
         this.getUserDetails();
}
async getUserDetails(){
        await this.props.UserStore.getUserDetails('1');
}
render () {
    const { isLoading, userDetails, error } = this.props.UserStore
        return (<View>
        {(!!isLoading)?<Text>{userDetails}</Text>:<Text>Loading</Text>}
        </View>)
}
```

UserStore.js

```
@observable userdetails = {};
@observable isLoading = false;
@observable error = {};

async getUserDetails(userID) {
        this.isLoading = true;
    try {
        await axios.get('http://192.168.1.9/user/' + userID)
              .then(response => {
               console.log('returned data from api / userstore '+response.data.user);
                this.userdetails = response.data.user;
                this.isLoading = false;
               })
               .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                    this.error = error
                })
     } catch (e) {
                console.log('ERROR', e);
               this.isLoading = false;
            }
        }
```

As you are passing the data into an observable array i.e. @observable userdetails = {}; Mobx will automatically update the state, once the promise / await is complete.

P.S. Mobx rules OK!! :o)

Comment: Hi, Thanks i'll give it a whirl and report back, just one thing what would be the reommended way of using isLoading within your solution? Thanks